# Smooth Edges of polygon in postGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, boundaries

I have a shape that looks like this:
[image]

It's the end result of a buffer, merge, bugffer and Chaikin Smoothing process in PostGIS. It's almost perfect however I'd like to remove some of the "fissures". If I could get the shape to have the boundary like the red line below it would be great. Ideally something I can do in postGIS.

[image]
Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning it up with [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html) or [ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html) should do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function made exactly for this problem: [ST_ConcaveHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html)

ST_Simplify can work, but it is not exactly the best option depending of the situation (it's not really what it's made for, and you will easily lose the details of the boundaries of your polygone while still having holes).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow when I'm back at work.

Comment: If you want you can also use it directly on your geometries for exemple with st_union (instead of the buffer/merge... process) and then maybe a buffer (dpending of your original problem)

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions to your problem

Create an external buffer by running the script:

`create table table_buf_exter as 
SELECT ST_Buffer((ST_Buffer(geom,0.007)),-0.007) geom 
FROM source_table`

Set the value of the buffer, so that they cover the width of the fine parts.

good luck in good deeds ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Answer (score 0):

Could you do the merge before the buffer?  Or buffer only partway, merge, and then buffer again?  That should not produce as many gores.